# No default network in Azure Docker

Tags: azure, docker, networking, docker-compose

I followed this turorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose

But when I set up my project there's no default network created.
Anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by the default network? The network for the containers when you deploy to the ACI? Or what else?

Comment: Anu updates? Do you still work on this?

Answer (score 0):

The default network should be bridge, as can be seen with

```
$ docker network ls
```

Whenever you start a container without providing `--network` flag your container is connected to the default bridge network by default. You can provide the `--network bridge` flag in your `docker run` command.

Alternatively, you can connect a container to a network using

```
$ docker network connect <network> <container>
```